# Webform not working

Tags: webforms

We're trying to get a custom module to work. For some reason, it's giving us an error, regardless of which version of Drupal we're trying to run. Here's the image:

[image: Image Here]

Also, are there any modules which can be a replacement for this one?

Comment: If you are working on a custom module, how is this question related to a Webform not working? You ask if there are any modules which can replace "this one" yet you provide no details on what features your custom module has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to delete from a table that doesn't exist.  That's why it doesn't matter what version of Drupal you're running.

What are you trying to achieve with your custom module?  Maybe you could post some example code.